# jquery's weird behaviour

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, post

I am using codeigniter framework and in view i am using jquery. Now, I have one select box which contains values from database. I tested the values of it using jquery change event and alert box. Its giving exact value in alert box on change, but when i am using post method or get or even $.ajax(), its not giving any output. In fact i checked with console.log(), its not going inside that too. I just need to post some values and get some info from database to show in the div just below that select box. 
Here's the code for jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#org_name').change(function(){
       $.post('index.php/contact/getorg',{'query':$('#org_name').val()},function(data){
         console.log("inside post"); 
         $('#showorg').html(data);
         console.log(org_name);
       });//close post function
   }); //close org_name event function
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code of your SELECT box? Unless you have an event attached to your form submit, jQuery shouldn't affect the data posted to the server.

Comment: Does the page get hit on the server? The content returned in "data" is html?

Comment: @Ryan - It isn't a `<form>` submit that's occurring here, he's going an AJAX call via `$.post()`, even if there was a form submit handler, it shouldn't have any affect on his `success` handler for the post.

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all in your console? Either Firebug in Firefox or the Developer Tools in Chrome are excellent tools for viewing requests like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am always using the following style...

```
ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'index.php/contact/getorg',
   data: JSON.stringify({'query':$('#org_name').val()}),
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function (data) {
      $('#showorg').html(JSON.parse(data.d));
   },
   error: showError
};

function showError(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            debugger;         }
```

EDIT:

And also the line `console.log(org_name);` seems not correct. Where is the member `org_name` comming from?

Comment: No clue if this is the problem. Maybe your url: is relative? Try '/index.php/contact/getorg'. Also, use firebug with firefox to diagnose xhr (ajax requests). Then you can see what's really happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.ajax` jQuery method with specified failure function (`error` variable) in method parameters. If something going wrong on server side or you have another specific error, you'll be able to analyze XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown variables

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response guys, that error call back method helped me a lot. It was giving 404 method, so i changed the url. Now its working like charm. Let me share with you all what i did:

```
$('#org_name').bind('change',function(){
  $("#showorg").html("wait...");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/ifes/index.php/contact/getorg',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data:{'query':$('#org_name').val()},
    timeout: 1000,
    error: function(xhr,err){
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#showorg').html(data);// do something with data
    }
  });  
});
```